# Testing configuration of ReactiveMongoTemplate with java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using `ReactiveMongoTemplate` in a java/spring application to connect to a database. How would I go about testing whether the connection between the application and the database is actually configured properly so that data can be inserted into the database?

Is there also a way to tell which further steps I would need to take if the connection hasn't been fully established?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a MongoDB instance during your application build and allow the tests to validate the connection logic. To make the setup portable you can either use [emebdded MongoDB](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) or [Docker with testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/tree/master/examples/mongodb-container).

Do note that if you have a standalone MongoDB server in different environments (e.g. PROD and TEST) with different connection configuration you can't really prove that it works until you try it out. If there is an error in PROD configuration (e.g. TEST username used instead of PROD username) you will only see when the application runs on PROD. This can be fixed by using [Kubernetes and immutable deployments](https://dyn.com/blog/kubernetes-what-is-immutable-infrastructure/).